# How to add JFreeChart in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jfreechart, windowbuilder

I am going to develop a Java application. It will collect the server counter information and shown it in a JFreeChart. I am going to develop this in Eclipse Kepler with the help of Window Builder. So anyone can help me by telling how to connect to Eclipse Window Builder with JFreeChart?

Comment: Are you just trying to add the library?

Comment: Download this [Install-pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/2.%20Documentation/1.0.17/). All the steps to configure are in Appendix A

Comment: @peeskillet: Good advice, but I suspect that user3099091 wants it to be available from the builder's palette.

Comment: mr.peeskillet, i just download the Jfreechart. But your given link redirect me to download page onle. there is no PDF for configure. Can you give me the coorect URL to configure JFreeChart with my Project.?

Answer (score 0):

1. place jfreechart jars somewhere on your hard drive (i placed mine in C:\Eclipse\ext_libraries)
2. Open Eclipse.
3. Start a new Java project like you normally would.
4. In the Package Explorer, right click your project and then click "Properties"
5. In the window that comes up, click the "Libraries" tab
6. Click "Add External JARs..."
7. Navigate to the folder you created, and highlight jcommon-1.0.x.jar (which ever version you have).
8. Click "Open"; this will add that jar to the list of external libraries.
9. Repeat 6-8 for jfreechart-1.0.x.jar and jfreechart-1.0.x-experimental.jar (if you want to use the experimental features)
10. You should now have access to the vast array of types, methods, objects, etc. that JFreeCharts provides; you'll of course, need to add "import org.jfree.chart.CLASS_YOU_WANT" to use them, but you should be able to copy and paste various samples available on the Net directly into Eclipse with little modification.